# Why do empty html elements behave differently than ones with content?

Tags: html, css

I wanted to show 12 square `button`s in 4 rows, similar to what a numpad looks like. For the purpose of this question, I broke the snippet down to 2 rows only.

```css
button {
  height: 64px;
  width: 64px;
  margin: 4px;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button>1</button>
  <button>2</button>
  <button>3</button>
</div>

<div>
  <button></button>
  <button>0</button>
  <button>back</button>
</div>
```

The Result for anyone who doesn't want to run the snippet:

[image: numpad]

As you can see, the first `button` in the last row does not have any content. As soon as I give it some content, the last row behaves the same as the other one. But if I leave it empty, the last 2 `button` "jump" because of it. I tried using `div`s instead of buttons, I tried packing each button inside a wrapper and applying the styles to the wrapper, but the result was always the same.

Can anyone please explain to me, where this behavior comes from? Am I missing something?

Comment: note that it behaves a little different on Firefox, the "0" and "back" are placed correctly, only the empty button is just slightly off

Comment: I think this will answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25790346/why-does-a-empty-button-doesnt-align-with-one-with-text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because by default `button` elements are vertically aligned at their `baseline` , which is either the last line of text or (if there is no content) the lower border, like in your image.

You can avoid that by adding `vertical-align: top;` or any other vertical-align setting.

```css
button {
  height: 64px;
  width: 64px;
  margin: 4px;
  background-color: grey;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button>1</button>
  <button>2</button>
  <button>3</button>
</div>

<div>
  <button></button>
  <button>0</button>
  <button>back</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to set the container div `display` attribut to `flex`

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

```css
button {
  height: 64px;
  width: 64px;
  margin: 4px;
  background-color: grey;
}

div{
  display: flex
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button>1</button>
  <button>2</button>
  <button>3</button>
</div>

<div>
  <button></button>
  <button>0</button>
  <button>back</button>
</div>
```